# Customize "Add to cart" button for a specific product category in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, button, woocommerce, product

This is my code:

```html
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'woo_custom_cart_button_text' );    // 2.1 +

function woo_custom_cart_button_text( $text ) {
    if( has_term( 'liners', 'product_cat' ) ){
        $text = __( ' ', 'your-plugin' );

          echo do_shortcode('<a href="#" class="popmake-923">Request а Quote</a>');
    }
    return $text;
}
```

I need to make function to replace the "Add to cart" button Url and Text for just one specific product category.

This button will trigger a Lightbox with a contact form and the text for this button will be: **Request a Quote**.

How can I make it work as expected?

Here is how it works actually on [**this link**](http://pladev.com/nni/product/french-bevel/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Updated:** for 2 different product categories (2 different buttons)

A global and complete solution for your products from 'liners' product category:

1. If one of your products (in 'liners' product category) is not a variable product, you need first to replace the add-to-cart button in shop and archives pages by a simple button linked to the product.
2. In single product pages you need to remove add-to-cart button and quantities fields, to replace it by your custom button.

Here is that code:

```
// Replacing the button add to cart by a link to the product in Shop and archives pages
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'conditionally_replacing_add_to_cart_button', 10, 2 );
function conditionally_replacing_add_to_cart_button( $button, $product  ) {

    $categories = array('liners','custom-classics');

    $product_id = method_exists( $product, 'get_id' ) ? $product->get_id() : $product->id;

    // For 'liners' product category
    if( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $product_id ) ){
        $button_text = __("View product", "woocommerce");
        $button = '<a class="button" href="' . $product->get_permalink() . '">' . $button_text . '</a>';
    }
    return $button;
}

// replacing add to cart button and quantities by your custom button in Single product pages
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'conditionally_replacing_template_single_add_to_cart', 1, 0 );
function conditionally_replacing_template_single_add_to_cart() {
    global $product;

    $categories = array('liners','custom-classics');

    $product_id = method_exists( $product, 'get_id' ) ? $product->get_id() : $product->id;

    function custom_button_replacement(){
        global $product;

        $categories = array('liners','custom-classics');

        $product_id = method_exists( $product, 'get_id' ) ? $product->get_id() : $product->id;

        if( has_term( $categories[0], 'product_cat', $product_id ) )
            $class_id = "923"; // liners
        elseif( has_term( $categories[1], 'product_cat', $product_id ) )
            $class_id = "925"; // custom-classics
        else $class_id = ""; // none

        // set below your custom text
        $button_text = __('Request а Quote', 'woocommerce');

        // Output your custom text
        echo '<a href="#" class="popmake-'.$class_id.' button">'.$button_text.'</a>';
    }

    // Only for 'liners' and 'custom-classics' product categories
    if( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $product_id ) ):
        // For variable product types
        if( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ){
            // Removing add to cart button and quantities
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button', 20 );

            // The button replacement
            add_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'custom_button_replacement', 20 );
        }
        else // For all other product types
        {
            // Removing add to cart button and quantities
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );

            // The button replacement
            add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_button_replacement', 30 );
        }
    endif;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested and works for all product types *(simple, variable…)*. You will get *(example)*:

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Thank you SOO much!! What if i need to do it for 2 different categories? I mean i need to call one pop up for one category, and different pop up for 2nd category? I just need to clone code below and change 'liners' to 'custom-samplers'?

Comment: Thank you! But it will call the same pop up. How to make 
        "echo '<button class="popmake-923 button">'.$button_text.'</button>';" with different value for "cat2"?

Comment: array('liners','custom-classics')

Comment: echo '<button class="popmake-923 button">'.$button_text.'</button>'; ....... echo '<button class="popmake-925 button">'.$button_text.'</button>';

Comment: @PhilippNoris Updated, tested and working for the 2 categories

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to replace the **Add to Cart** button with a **Read More** button, with class and id in a certain category.

```
   /* // Replace the Add to Cart Btn in Category Ammunition with View Product Btn  */

      add_filter('woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link','change_simple_shop_add_to_cart',10,2);
      function change_simple_shop_add_to_cart( $html, $product ){


           $category_ammunition = $product->get_categories();


          if (strstr($category_ammunition, 'Ammunition')) { // Add Your Category Here 'Ammuntion'

     $html = sprintf( '<a id="read-more-btn" rel="nofollow" href="%s" data-product_id="%s"  class="button vp-btn">%s</a>',
                      esc_url( get_the_permalink() ),
                      esc_attr( $product->get_id() ),
                      esc_html(  __( 'Read More', 'woocommerce' ) )
              );
              $category_ammunition = $product->get_categories();
          }

          return $html;
      }
```