# Woocommerce - Remove add to cart button functionality and change button text

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product

In WooCommerce I would like to replace add to cart button and change it to "Read More" **but only for certain product categories**.

I've tried using quite a few different code snippets for this but nothing seems to give me the results I'm wanting.

The reason is that I want to use certain sections of my shop as a product catalog displaying items and their prices but not allowing users to purchase them.

Does anyone know how/if this would be possible?

Any help at all would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please do some more research, there are plenty of catalog mode plugins out there that can do this for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some functions that will replace **for some defined product categories** only:

1. *In Shop and archives pages:* The button add to cart by a link to the product
2. *In Single product pages:* add to cart button and quantities by your custom button

You will have to define in that fuctions:

1. The product categories in the arrays (2 times)
2. The  "Read more" button product link (for simple product pages)

Here is the code:

```
// Replacing the button add to cart by a link to the product in Shop and archives pages
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'replacing_conditionally_loop_add_to_cart_button', 10, 2 );
function replacing_conditionally_loop_add_to_cart_button( $button, $product  ) {
    // Set HERE your product categories in the array
    $categories = array( 't-shirts', 'gloves' );

    if( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ){
        $button_text = __( "View product", "woocommerce" );
        $button = '<a class="button" href="' . $product->get_permalink() . '">' . $button_text . '</a>';
    }
    return $button;
}


// Button replacement function for Single product pages (SET the link below)
function custom_button_read_more( $product_link ){
    global $product;

    // Set HERE your product link
    $product_link = home_url( '/some-link-to-define/' );

    $button_text = __('Read more', 'woocommerce');
    echo '<a href="'.$product_link.'" class="button">'.$button_text.'</a>';
}


// replacing add to cart button and quantities by your custom button in Single product pages
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'replacing_conditionally_template_single_add_to_cart', 1, 0 );
function replacing_conditionally_template_single_add_to_cart() {
    global $product;

    // Set HERE your product categories in the array
    $categories = array( 't-shirts', 'gloves' );

    if( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $product->get_id()) ){

        // For variable product types
        if( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ){
            // Removing add to cart button and quantities
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button', 20 );

            // The button replacement
            add_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'custom_button_read_more', 20 );
        }
        else // For all other product types
        {
            // Removing add to cart button and quantities
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );

            // The button replacement
            add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_button_read_more', 30 );
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

All code is tested on Woocommerce 3+ and works.

---

Similar answer: [Customize "Add to cart" button for a specific product category in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46005902/customize-add-to-cart-button-for-a-specific-product-category-in-woocommerce/46008870#46008870)

Comment: Hey @LoicTheAztec, Sorry for the delay in trying this code out. But ive just tested it (on woocommerce 3.1.2) and it isnt working. Any ideas? Im ive currently got this pasted in my fuctions.php https://hastebin.com/dimurugoyo.php

Comment: @LBlakemore I really don't know why is not working for you… May be your theme has already some customizations… I have retested the code and it's perfectly working for me on 2 different test servers (WC 3.1.2 too)…